# Who do I ask when I detect a vulnerability in Linux source code?

Tags: linux, vulnerabilities

I am working on vulnerability detection in open source software including Linux. I have discovered vulnerable source code in the latest version of Linux. Who should I inform about this vulnerable source code?

Please let me know so that this code can be modified.

Comment: If it is a particular flavour of linux - you should contact them directly. So if it happens to be an Ubuntu source - then advise to the Ubuntu team (or whoever code it is)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that by “Linux”, you mean the Linux kernel. According to [`kernel.org`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/admin-guide/security-bugs.html):

> Please report security bugs to the Linux kernel security team.
>
> The Linux kernel security team can be contacted by email at `security@kernel.org`. This is a private list of security officers who will help verify the bug report and develop and release a fix. If you already have a fix, please include it with your report, as that can speed up the process considerably. It is possible that the security team will bring in extra help from area maintainers to understand and fix the security vulnerability.

If instead the bug is with a particular piece of software specific to a distribution, you should have a look at the respective documentation from the distribution vendor. For example, for Ubuntu, you can find [information here](https://usn.ubuntu.com/).